# Trying to create a discovery script using Python Multithreadinig

Tags: python, multithreading, networking

I'm trying to create a discovery script, which will use multithreading to ping multiple IP addresses at once.

```
import ipaddress
import sh
from threading import Thread
from Queue import Queue


user_input = raw_input("")
network = ipaddress.ip_network(unicode(user_input))

def pingit(x):

    for i in x.hosts():
        try:
            sh.ping(i, "-c 1")
            print i, "is active"
        except sh.ErrorReturnCode_1:
            print "no response from", i

queue_to_work = Queue(maxsize=0)
number_of_workers = 30

for i in range(number_of_workers):
    workers = Thread(target=pingit(network),args=(queue_to_work,))
    workers.getDaemon(True)
    workers.start()
```

When I run this script, I get the ping responses, but it is not fast. I believe the multithreading is not kicking in.

Could someone please tell me where I'm going wrong?

Many thanks.

Comment: Looking at your question I'm wondering why you would like to use multithreading for this task. It seems like a Distributed Task Queue (like Celery) would be more suited for the task at hand. Could you provide a bit more context on what you would like to achieve?

Comment: @JohanVergeer, I'm trying to discover the active and inactive Ip addresses on a network. My first script below

`for i in x.hosts():
  try:
   sh.ping(i, "-c 1")
   print i, "is active"
  except sh.ErrorReturnCode_1:
   print "no response from", i`

but, that was really slow. I tried looking some tutorial and came across multithreading. I thought I can ping 30 IP addresses at once if I use multithreading.

Any help or direction would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are doing it completely wrong.

```
import ipaddress
import sh
from threading import Thread

user_input = raw_input("")
network = ipaddress.ip_network(unicode(user_input))

def pingit(x):

    for i in x.hosts():
        try:
            sh.ping(i, "-c 1")
            print i, "is active"
        except sh.ErrorReturnCode_1:
            print "no response from", i

workers = Thread(target=pingit,args=(network,))
workers.start()
```

This is how you start a thread. Writing `pingit(network)` will actually run the function, and pass its result into `Thread`, while you want to pass the function itself. You should pass function `pingit` and the argument `network` separately. Note this creates a thread that practically run `pingit(network)`.

Now, if you want to use multiple threads, you can do so in a loop. But you also have to create separate sets of data to feed into the threads. Consider you have a list of hosts, e.g. `['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']`, and you want to ping them from two threads. You have to create two threads, that call `pingit(['A', 'B'])` and `pingit(['C', 'D'])`.

As a side note, don't use `ip_network` to find the ip addresses, use `ip_address`. You can ping an ip address, but not a network. Of course if you want to ping *all* ip addresses in the network, `ip_network` is fine.

You may want to somehow split the user input into multiple ip addresses and separate the list into sublists for your threads. This is pretty easy. Now you can write a `for` to create threads, and feed each sublist into arguments of the thread. This creates threads that actually run with different parameters.

Comment: Also, if you have a high number of threads, consider using a thread pool. Search the term, there are a lot of info about it.

Comment: Thank you so much @vsoraki. This is more than enough, you just lightened me up.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to share my thoughts on this.

Since I guess this is something you would like to run in the background, I would suggest you use a Queue instead of a Thread.

This will offer you multiple advantages:

- You can add multiple functionalities into the queue
- If something happens, the queue will just continue, and catch the error for you. You can even add some logging to it in case something goes wrong.
- The queue runs as a daemon, with every item in the queue as it's own process
- Systems like RabbitMQ or Redis are build for this specific kind of task.
- It is relatively easy to setup

I have created a simple script for you that you might be able to use:

```
import subprocess

from celery import Celery

app = Celery()

@app.task
def check_host(ip, port=80, timeout=1):
    output = subprocess.Popen(["ping", "-c", "1", ip], stdout=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()[0]

    if "1 packets received" in output.decode("utf-8"):
        return "{ip} connected successfully".format_map(vars())
    else:
        return "{ip} was unable to connect".format_map(vars())


def pingit(ip="8.8.8.8"):    

    check_host.delay(ip)
```

What this does is the following.

1. You first import Celery, this will make you able to connect to Celery that runs in the background.
2. You create an app which is in instance of the Celery class
3. You use this app to create a task. Inside this you put task all the actions you want to perform async.
4. You call the delay() method on the task

Now task will run on the background, and all other tasks will be put in the queue to run async for you. 
So you can just put everything in a loop, and the Queue will handle it for you.

The information about Celery: http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/getting-started/first-steps-with-celery.html
And a great tutorial to get everything setup I found on YouTube: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=68QWZU_gCDA

I hope this can help you a bit further

Comment: this is very helpful. I will research more about this.